# nth-of-class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="class_1"></div>
  <div class="class_1"></div>
  <div class="class_2"></div>
  <div class="class_2"></div>
  <div class="class_2"></div>
  <div class="class_2"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to select **every second** `.class_2` using jQuery?

I don't want to select any other div in `#wrapper`

What I've tried:

> `:nth-child` - this is counting all divs
>
> `:nth-of-type` - this is also counting all divs

I want to select for example every second div only with `.class_2` and add some class.

Comment: $('#wrapper class_2'), Hey Is this you are asking for?,

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You will need to close those div tags.

Comment: For clarity, are you referring to only selecting the 4th "class" div in your example?

Comment: Really not clear question IMO

Comment: So in your example, would one or two `class_2` divs be selected? I'm confused.

Comment: @j08691 want to sellect 2 divs only with class `.class_2` (second and 4th)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem:

> "I want to select for example every second div only with `.class_2`"

### Solution:

I believe you could use **[`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)** in this instance, e.g:

```
$('#wrapper > div.class_2:odd')
```

Although concatenating `:odd` with **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** would actually be the faster way:

```
$('#wrapper > div.class_2').filter(':odd')
```

This selects every div with `class_2`, and filters them based on whether or not they are odd or even.

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/DqaqC/1/)**

### Why are you using :odd and not :even then?

**[0-based indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering)** actually means that ironically, `:odd` selects the second, fourth, sixth element etc.

Comment: this looks fine :) ... is possible to edit this somehow to select every 4th or every 3th element?

Comment: See my answer, you can edit '2n' to every nth-number you want!

Comment: Take it easy, I didn't ;-) Your `:odd`-function is clear and is an good answer on the question.

Comment: @Zenith no your answer is valid and helpfull! :)
I am just wondering for the future use

Answer (score -1):

The second, i.e not 0, 1, not 2, not 3, etc... ? Or not 0, 1, not 2, 3, not 4 etc... ?
If only the second :

```
$('div.class_2:nth-child(2)')
```

Else as said in other answers :

```
$('div.class_2:odd')
```